# How do I get properly escaped XML in python etree untouched?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I'm using python version 2.7.3.

**test.txt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <test>The tag &lt;StackOverflow&gt; is good to bring up at parties.</test>
</root>
```

**Result:**

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> e = ET.parse('test.txt')
>>> root = e.getroot()
>>> print root.find('test').text
The tag <StackOverflow> is good to bring up at parties.
```

As you can see, the parser must have changed the `&lt;`'s to `<`'s etc.

**What I'd like to see:**

`The tag &lt;StackOverflow&gt; is good to bring up at parties.`

Untouched, raw text. Sometimes I really like it raw. Uncooked.

I'd like to use this text as-is for display within HTML, therefore I don't want an XML parser to mess with it.

Do I have to re-escape each string or can there be another way?

Comment: For displaying in other sources, simply re-escape! It's a parser's *job* to give you the proper XML contents after parsing, and HTML escaping can be subtly different *anyway*.

Comment: Fair point, will probably do that. Just was curious if there's some option in the parser or such.

Answer (score 5):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
e = ET.parse('test.txt')
root = e.getroot()
print(ET.tostring(root.find('test')))
```

yields

```
<test>The tag &lt;StackOverflow&gt; is good to bring up at parties.</test>
```

Alternatively, you could escape the text with [saxutils.escape](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.escape):

```
import xml.sax.saxutils as saxutils
print(saxutils.escape(root.find('test').text))
```

yields

```
The tag &lt;StackOverflow&gt; is good to bring up at parties.
```

Comment: Both cases simply re-escape the value.